# how to add update before select

Tags: php, sql, telegram

how do I update the data of users who have already logged in before (their user_id is recorded) before taking them from the database in this line
`$user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_shop_profile WHERE user_id = :user_id"); $user->execute(['user_id' => $chat_id]);`
full listing

````
    {
        $user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_shop_profile WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $user->execute(['user_id' => $chat_id]);
        if ($user->rowCount() == 0) {
            $newUser = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO bot_shop_profile SET user_id = :user_id, first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name, phone = :phone, adress = :adress, action = 'start', username = :username");
            $newUser->execute([
                'user_id' => $chat_id,
                'first_name' => $data['message']['chat']['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['message']['chat']['last_name'],
                'username' => $data['message']['chat']['username'],
                'phone' => '',
                'adress' => '',
            ]);
        } else {
            @$this->setActionUser("start", $chat_id);
        }
        
        
    }```

I think it should be an expression with UPDATE
````

Comment: If you reorganised your code a little bit - and presuming `user_id` is a unique key in `bot_shop_profile` - you could do a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` query first, then do your `SELECT`

Comment: I want to change the part before"if" (everything below suits me), so I need to immediately update for all fields, the problem is that I'm confused about $user = $this->pdo->prepare and $user->execute

Answer (score 1):

you can use the UPDATE statement to modify existing records in the database. In your case, you want to update the user's information if the user with the specified user_id already exists. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
$user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_shop_profile WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$user->execute(['user_id' => $chat_id]);

if ($user->rowCount() == 0) {
    // User doesn't exist, insert a new record
    $newUser = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO bot_shop_profile SET user_id = :user_id, first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name, phone = :phone, address = :address, action = 'start', username = :username");
    $newUser->execute([
        'user_id' => $chat_id,
        'first_name' => $data['message']['chat']['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['message']['chat']['last_name'],
        'username' => $data['message']['chat']['username'],
        'phone' => '',
        'address' => '',
    ]);
} else {
    // User exists, update the existing record
    $updateUser = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE bot_shop_profile SET first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name, username = :username WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $updateUser->execute([
        'user_id' => $chat_id,
        'first_name' => $data['message']['chat']['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['message']['chat']['last_name'],
        'username' => $data['message']['chat']['username'],
    ]);

    $this->setActionUser("start", $chat_id);
}
```

This code first checks if the user with the given user_id exists. If not, it inserts a new record. If the user already exists, it updates the existing record with the new information. Adjust the column names and values in the UPDATE statement according to your database schema.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you very much